# Wordpress Site Loading Speed to Slow: 8.13s

Tags: wordpress, performance, page-speed

My wordpress website is extremely slow on loading the page. It's takin 8.3 seconds from Frankfurt sometimes more.

I am using Bluehost and I have heard it's slower but this seems too much...

You can see the waterfall here: https://tools.pingdom.com/#5a253be0d4c00000

I noticed it has huge waiting times for the main page...

I have tried multiple things but had no success in bringing it down.

I am now using W3Cache but it's not helping much..., the loading speed is much the same. I have used it on other sites before with better results...

I have also changed most of the images by .jpg images that I optimized.

Does any one have any ideas or what I can do to bring the loading speed down to at least 4s? It's 8s right now And any intel on why this is happening and how I can solve it would be great!

Comment: "Tell me what is wrong with my site" questions won't be useful to the next visitor.

Answer (score 0):

Your images are huge in comparison to the size they are being used at.

You should reduce the size of your images to the maximum size they will be displayed at.

Follow this with a trip to https://tinypng.com/ putting all of your assets through there.

Re-upload them, clear your cache.

This is a solid start - come back once you have done this and I can find more parts that can help speed the site up.

[image: image-size]
[image: image-size-2]

Ta, J.